# ExcelProvider is not defined - how resolve this error?

Tags: excel, f#, type-providers

I am trying to get a type provider working with Excel.  This is  my first time and I am having trouble.  I downloaded FsharpX.ExcelProvider from Nuget.

Here is my code:

```
namespace xxxx

open System
open System.IO
open FSharpx.TypeProviders

type TimesheetRow = ExcelProvider<"C:\SourceModules\MyFile.xlsm","Timesheet",true>
```

The problem is that there are red squigglies under ExcelProvider, and the fly-over message is **ExcelProvider is not define**

Can someone help me know what I need to do here to resolve this problem?

Possibly pertinent: Visual Studio 2013 with Office 2010 installed.

I am still trying stuff as I wait for answers.  When I type in the full name, FSharpx.TypeProviders. intellisense gives me the choice of ExcelProvider.  So it is there.

Comment: What are your references?

Comment: FSharp.Core, FSharpx.TypeProviders.Excel, mscorlib, System System.Core, System.Numerics

Comment: Did it ask you to enable provider when you installed nuget? You can also check this in F# Settings

Comment: Dmitry, it asked me something, but it was last night, and I do not recall how I answered it.  Where would I find the F# Settings?  Options / F# Tools?  All I see there is a list of Trusted Assemblies, and I have checked TypeProviders.Excel ON.

Comment: Okay, so I have abandoned this effort and I'm doing what I need to do in C#.  (It was meant to be a learning exercise in F# for me, but I can learn later.)  What is the recommended approach to this situation regarding my question when I don't need to ask it any more?  Delete my own question?  Others?

Answer (score 0):

What John Palmer said: What are your references?

That is, if its not there already; add the package ExcelDataReader, and possibly the world looks much better...

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/